# UITableView index beyond bounds error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am experiencing an error at the following line:

```
cell1.textLabel.text = [settings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

And this is the uncaught inception error i receive:

> ```
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException',
>     reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
> First throw call stack:
> (0x2265012 ... 0x21a5 0x1)
> libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
> (lldb)
> ```

Here's my code:

**.h:**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource ,UITableViewDelegate>{

    //Settings Table
    IBOutlet UITableView *settingTable;
    NSMutableArray *settings;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *settingTable;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *settings;
```

**.m:**

```
@synthesize settingTable;
@synthesize settings;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (!settings) {
        return 0;
    }

    if ([settings count] > 0){
        return [settings count];
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (settingTable) {

        NSLog(@"%@", settings);

        UITableViewCell *cell1 = [settingTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell1"];
        if (cell1 == nil) {
            cell1 = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell1"];
        }

        cell1.textLabel.text = [settings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell1;
   }

// ...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    settingTable.delegate = self;
    settingTable.dataSource = self;

    //settings table
    settings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Downloads", @"Queue", @"FAQ", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and add what 'settings' looks like when you use the NSLog on it just before the crash? Also, if you haven't already done so, I would set an exception breakpoint, this will cause the debugger to stop a bit earlier on some crash situations.

Comment: Try creating settings array first, then set delegate and dataSource properties for tableView, and then call [tableView reloadData];

Comment: I don't see where you're initializing `settingTable`.  Where is the rest of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?  Why are you even checking if `settingTable` is `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your settings to be initialized like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    settingTable.delegate = self;
    settingTable.dataSource = self;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)settings
{
    if (!_settings) settings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Downloads", @"Queue", @"FAQ", nil];
    return _settings;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return settings.count;
}
```

This way your settings object is always initialized.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `indexPath.row == 3` causing the crash.

Comment: With the code posted above, it won't ever be 3. Since the settings object is mutable, are you adding/removing items from it anywhere?

Comment: In the slog it is showing all items in the array but still crashing when opening the tableview

Comment: If you set a breakpoint/log on settings.count in the numberOfRowsInSection method, is the count actually 3 there? Also, is the datasource for your table view hooked up to a different view controller? I could see how having the datasource and delegate pointed at two different controllers may cause this issue.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are using static cells in UITableView. Just increase number of rows in your storyboard. It is the maximum count of cell you can add to Table View programmatically.

*Sorry i didn't see that you're not using storyboard. But my answer is correct for those who are using it.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using story board and static table then one of the two things can work:

1> number of cell should be same in story boad which returning number of rows.

or

2> if you want to keep one cell in story board then implement indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath datasource methods.In rang exception if you trace the stack then you will find various data source method that you need to implement,because in dynamic prototype table it will take care it self but in static we need to implement datasource methods

Answer (score -1):

For cleaning up the code,you can do the followings :

1.In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, use

```
if([settings count]>0)
```

instead of

```
if(settingTable)
```

2.In the numberOfRowsInSection method,use

```
if ([settings count] > 0){
    return [settings count];    
}
else
    return 0;
```

instead of

```
if(!settings){
    return 0;
}
if ([settings count] > 0){
    return [settings count];

}
else
    return 0;
```

The above changes in your code will make your code working perfectly.

Comment: This doesn't address the problem.  Why is `indexPath.row == 3`?

Comment: @BrianNickel If the setting array has 3 elements and numberOfRowsInSection returns 3 (the no. of elements in the array,not the highest index of the array).So when indexPath.row is called,it will be 3,indexPath.row starts from 0 and ends at 2.So there will be no error.

Comment: Right, but the question is about this error: `'-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'`.

Answer (score -1):

Just change it the line to:

```
cell1.textLabel.text = [settings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
```

Comment: This would cause a crash at index path `(0, 0)`.